# Export data from Mysql to Excel

Tags: php, mysql

**I'm using php script to export data from Mysql database to Excel sheet..
While opening the excel file,I'm facing with the following error..
Error found unreadable content in codenovssem.xls
Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook?
If you trust the source of the workbook click yes...
when I clicked Yes It's displaying like this "Unable to read file.."
I've used the following code**

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from t3diff ");//retrieving records from database
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/x-msexcel;charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=codenovsem.xls "); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
xlsBOF();
/*
Make a top line on your excel sheet at line 1 (starting at 0).
The first number is the row number and the second number is the column, 
both are start       at '0'
*/
xlsWriteLabel(0,0,"student Marks" );
// Make column labels. (at line 3)
xlsWriteLabel(2,0,"codeno");
xlsWriteLabel(2,1,"na");
xlsWriteLabel(2,2,"marks");
xlsWriteLabel(2,3,"subname");
xlsWriteLabel(2,4,"subcode");
xlsWriteLabel(2,5,"branch");
xlsWriteLabel(2,6,"year");
xlsWriteLabel(2,7,"sem");
xlsWriteLabel(2,8,"setno");
xlsWriteLabel(2,9,"bundleno");
xlsWriteLabel(2,10,"afor");
xlsWriteLabel(2,11,"oname");
xlsWriteLabel(2,12,"valdate");
xlsWriteLabel(2,13,"valtime");
$xlsRow =  3;
// Put data records from mysql by while loop.
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
xlsWriteNumber($xlsRow,0,$row['codeno']);
xlsWriteNumber($xlsRow,1,$row['na']);
xlsWriteNumber($xlsRow,2,$row['marks']);
xlsWriteNumber($xlsRow,3,$row['subname']);
xlsWriteNumber($xlsRow,4,$row['subcode']);
xlsWriteNumber($xlsRow,5,$row['branch']);
xlsWriteNumber($xlsRow,6,$row['year']);
xlsWriteNumber($xlsRow,7,$row['sem']);
xlsWriteNumber($xlsRow,8,$row['setno']);
xlsWriteNumber($xlsRow,9,$row['bundleno']);
xlsWriteNumber($xlsRow,10,$row['afor']);
xlsWriteNumber($xlsRow,11,$row['oname']);
xlsWriteNumber($xlsRow,12,$row['valdate']);
xlsWriteNumber($xlsRow,13,$row['valtime']);
$xlsRow++;
} 
xlsEOF();//End of Excel file
exit();
```

Comment: Open the xls file in notepad and see if there are PHP errors/warnings in that file. If not then file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue a few days ago. Actually you do not export a real .xls file. It is still a text file which has .xls extension.

So I suggest you to use http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

It is 100% successful for creating xls files. Also it has an amazing documentation.